# How to ignore parent view's padding SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-layout

I have a VStack with multiple child views (the one with blue background). The VStack has horizontal padding. I want to have this padding set for each child, but sometimes I have exception where I want that child to reach edges of the display completely (Two grey lines above "Checkout" button). Is there any way how to allow this to happen? I don't wanna set padding for every single child separately.

[image]

Comment: children always follow parent's padding. try to move your line same level as your vstack. such as 
VStack { VStack { items } Divider() VStack { checkoutButton } }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply a negative padding on the view that you applied on the VStack, that means if you applied a padding of 16 points to the VStack like this for example `.padding(16)` for all directions which is the default. then you can apply a `.padding(.horizontal,-16)` to the lines and they will stretch to the end of the screen

here is a sample code and a screenshot for the behavior you want.
[image: Screenshot]

```swift
struct VStackPadding: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .frame(width: .infinity,height: 3)
                .padding(.horizontal, -16)
                .padding(.bottom,16)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                .frame(width: .infinity,height: 3)
        }.padding(16)
    }
}
```